# Activerecord query help me

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I do query in `activerecord` like this:

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(col1) AS count FROM tab1 
WHERE col2='sometext' 
GROUP BY col1 
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Expected Output:

```
col1    count
--------------
name1   247
name5   182
name4   96
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
Model
  .select('col1, COUNT(col1) AS count')
  .where(col2: 'sometext')
  .group(:col1)
  .order('count DESC')
  .limit(10)
```